# LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren returning empty list

Tags: wpf

If a wpf datepicker is placed in a grid in a wpf window:

```
var children = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(datePicker1);
```

returns an empty list when used in the windows loaded handler. Please could someone explain why this happens?

The following works when the datepicker's visibility property is set to visibile. I have a scenario where the datepicker is not visible on startup, hence looking at using LogicalTreeHelper instead:

```
private void DatePickerLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            var tb = GetChildOfType<DatePickerTextBox>(this);
            if (tb == null) return;

            var wm = tb.Template.FindName("PART_Watermark", tb) as ContentControl;
            if (wm == null) return;

            wm.Content = string.Empty;

            DisplayDateStart = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1);
            DisplayDateEnd = new DateTime(2100, 12, 31);
        }

        public T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (dependencyObject == null) return null;

            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);

                var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
                if (result != null) return result;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: What children do you expect the DatePicker to have? It is not a container and hence has no children.

Comment: @Clemens thanks, good question, what does a child mean in the context of GetChildren? please see updated question which indicates there are children.

Comment: You are confusing visual and logical children here, or the [visual tree and the logical tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx).

Comment: @Clemens thanks for the link. However, if VisualTreeHelper returns children, should LogicalTreeHelper not do so?

Comment: OK, link states "The visuals that come from an applied template (such as the template-defined Border of dark gray around the visual button) are not reported in the logical tree, even if you are looking at the logical tree during run time" so the logical tree seems a smaller subset; seems as though logical tree only contains actual children (i.e. children or item properties)

Comment: The visual children of a DatePicker are internal and not part of a logical tree. DatePicker is not a ContentControl and its internals are not part of your application's __object graph__ as mentioned in the linked page.

Comment: Made this explanation an answer, so that it can be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

DatePicker does not have [logical children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx#logical_tree).

The visual children of a DatePicker are internal and not part of a logical tree. DatePicker is not a ContentControl and its internals are not part of your application's *object graph* as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx).